# A value of type 'Future<bool?>' can't be returned from the method because it has a return type of 'Future<bool>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
Future<bool> foo(BuildContext context) {
  return Navigator.pushNamed<bool>(context, '/bar'); // Error
}
```

Error:

> A value of type 'Future<bool?>' can't be returned from the function 'foo' because it has a return type of 'Future'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Navigator.push` can't return a non-nullable type because in your `/bar` route, you could probably do the following without passing any value in the result parameter.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

You should change your signature from `Future<bool>` to `Future<bool?>`:

```dart
Future<bool?> foo(BuildContext context) {
  return Navigator.pushNamed<bool>(context, '/bar');
}
```